# Faq doesn't explain reputation I got for an answer

Tags: bug, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [invisible, unawarded upvote](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/invisible-unawarded-upvote)

My answer got 10 upvotes, and according to [my user page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/25554/mark-dominus), I received 10 reputation points for the first 9 upvotes, and 6 reputation points for the 10th upvote.  Either the display is wrong, or [the explanation on the FAQ list](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) is wrong.

Here are screenshots of the relevant parts of my user page:

[image: screenshot]
[image: secreenshot 2]

What's going on? Documentation error, or software error? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aha, I bet it's because I hit the 200-per-day cap for the first time.

Comment: yes, right.${}$

Comment: What do I do now? Just delete the question?

Comment: No need to. I am fishing out a duplicate to close this question. But, if you'd like to delete there is no problem. BTW, I +1'd your answer. :)

Comment: @KannappanSampath Closing a a duplicate of [invisible, unawarded upvote](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/) sounds good to me.

Comment: Done now. :) ${}$

Comment: You'll be getting the Mortarboard badge any time now...